# Passing an operator to a function?

Tags: ruby

Perhaps this just sounds ridiculous but I'm wondering is this possible with Ruby? Basically I have a function...

```
def add a,b
 c = a + b
 return c
end
```

I'd like to be able to pass the "+" or another operator e.g "-" to the function so that it'd be something like...

```
def sum a,b,operator
 c = a operator b
 return c
end
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two possibilities:

Take method/operator name as a symbol:

```
def sum a,b,operator
 a.send(operator, b)
end
sum 42, 23, :+
```

Or the more general solution: Take a block:

```
def sum a,b
  yield a,b
end
sum 42, 23, &:+
```

Answer (score 3):

```
4.send("+", 5)
```

Returns `9`

http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#M001077